# Targeting CSS elements - Fontawesome and Glyphicons

Tags: css, font-awesome, glyphicons

I'm having some trouble getting Font Awesome and Glyphicons the same side in my side bar menu. I'm unsure how to target the elements to set a specific font size?

A snip of the side bar code.

```
<div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
    <ul class="list-group sidebar-nav-v1" id="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="list-group-item list-toggle active">
            <a aria-expanded="true" class="" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-group-6">My Account</a>
            <ul aria-expanded="true" class="collapse in" id="collapse-group-6" style="">
                <li class="my_account_links_inactive">
                    <a class="user_links" href="index.php?a=4&amp;b=12">
                    <div class="my_account_icons">
                        <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                    </div>print signs and flyers</a>
                </li>
                <li class="my_account_links_inactive">
                    <a class="user_links" href="store/The-Parts-Network.html">
                    <div class="my_account_icons">
                        <i class="glyphicons white shop"></i>
                    </div>my storefront</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think I need something like this?

```
    #sidebar-nav > li > ul > li > a > div > i [class*="fa-"],
    #sidebar-nav > li > ul >li > a > div > i[class*="glyphicon-"] {
    font-size: 16px;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the actual class? Like: `i.glyphicons, i.fa {font-size: 16px;}`

Comment: They're used all over my site / different sizes. I want to target just the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

This CSS should work to target the `#sidebar-nav` icons only:

```
#sidebar-nav i.glyphicons, #sidebar-nav i.fa {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: This targets, but it wont change the size of the Glyphicon (FA ok). Width and size attributes don't seem to work either. I'm using Glyphicons Pro 1.8.1 if this changes anything?

Comment: Can you post a snippet to JSFiddle or similar? Looking at: http://glyphicons.com/ and changing the `.font-list .glyphicons` font-size using inspect element in Chrome works. So it should be working.